# is there MouseChildren for CALayer hit test?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, calayer, hittest

Hey.
i have a main layer that contains a 4 circle layers and inside each circle there is a text layer :

main layer -> (4)circle layer -> (1)textLayer.

I am performing hit test on the main layer and i want to receive the circle that was clicked.
It works fine, but when I tap in the text area i get back the text layer and not the circle layer.

In AS3 you have

```
 MouseChildren = true/false.
```

How can i get this functionality in objective c?

thanks

shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `superlayer` property, like this:

```
if([theLayer isKindOfClass:[CATextLayer class]])
    theLayer = theLayer.superlayer;
```

In other words, if you've already got the circle layer, `theLayer` doesn't change; if it's one of the text sublayers, `theLayer` changes to point to the layer that contains that sublayer.